# Conditional copy/paste cells from sheet to sheet based on overlapping content in A columns?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Excel 2011, Mac.

Two sheets, both with names in "last, first" descending in A.
The name list of sheet 1 is much shorter than the name list on sheet 2.
Sheet 2 has the headings there in row 1, but the rest of the cells in those 12 columns have been left blank.

I need to get 12 columns of data from the names in sheet 1 into the right rows of sheet 2.

I tied to use a pivot table, but the pivot brought over 0s and 1s instead of the actual data in sheet1, though it did bring over the headings. I used that pivot (copy/paste) to create the normal sheet I am copying into with this task.

I tried to figure out a way to code this that makes sense, but fell on my face because I cant figure out how to go about it without making it overly complicated.

I could add rows between matching names until A matches A, then copy and paste the whole block of cells at once.
I could find matches and copy data into in Sheet2 as I go.
I could build a list(array?) of matches then go through and copy each match's stuff over...
Ugh. I just KNOW these are kludgy ideas, but obviously I can't find anything better in searches - or at least my search terms are useless when hunting for them.

So I am not asking for *all* the code, but am asking for two things:

1) Code to efficiently do this comparison between the names in both sheets' A columns.

2) Suggestions on the logical operations process that would be *fastest* to code (the least to figure out for me, that is).

Eg:

```
Underscore indicates empty cell.

Sheet 1          Sheet 2

   A   B   C...        A  B  C  D...
1  A  22  11       1   A  _  _  547
2  C  32  21       2   B  _  _  678
3  F  56  89       3   C  _  _  34
4  H  65  90       4   D  _  _  67899
.                  5   E  _  _  875
.                  6   F  _  _  875
.                  7   G  _  _  875
                   8   H  _  _  875

Resulting Sheet 2

   A   B   C   D...
1  A  22  11  547
2  B  _   _   678
3  C  32  21  34
4  D  _   _   67899
5  E  _   _   875
6  F  56  89  875   
7  G  _   _   875
8  H  65  90  875
.
.
.
```

So, your thoughts would be appreciated, and your code welcome!

Comment: Does sheet 1 cointains data in approriate rows ? or your example of sheet 1 is just to show a where data should go to? I mean is sheet 1 for example B1 a blank cell or data there should be omitted.

Comment: I didn't indicate the row numbers and column letters in the example, it just shows the data in the cells.Sheet1 B1 would have "22" in the above example of the layout. Sheet1 B2 has "32".

Comment: Will now edit the question to better reflect Excel column and row labels.

Comment: Well... still not sure... How are you matching data from sheet 1 to sheet 2? What makes you sure that data from sheet 1 row fits to certain sheet 2 row?

Comment: Data matching happens when items in both A columns match. Like when Sheet1 A1 = Sheet2 A1 in the above example, it triggers the copy and paste of data from (Sheet 1: B1, C1) into (Sheet 2: B1, C1).
The actual data range's width is a known (12 columns instead of the 2 in the example), and the known 12 column wide target area in Sheet 2 is empty.

Comment: If I understood you correctly it's enough to do "for next" loop and add matching condition with "if then". If you provide me actual workbook with sample of data I can write you that code. Oh and one more thing: you know excact number of columns and how about rows?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider getting your code to add a vlookup formula to Sheet2 B1 and C1, then copying the formula down (if you have lots of rows, the calculation time is considerable, though). Then copy/pasteSpecial Values in Sheet2 B and C to get rid of the formula.

Alternatively you can loop through all the values in Sheet2 column A and look for a match in Sheet1.

Let me know if you need some sample code.